# mi logo no aparece al momento de subir el proyecto de laravel al servidor

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

lo llamo asi de esta forma mi imagen dentro de la etiqueta `img`

```
src="{{ asset('/img/icons/logogeotracking.PNG') }}"
```

y esta guardada en la carpeta `public/img/icons/logogeotracking.PNG`

Comment: la imagen la subes directamente a la carpeta public? o a subes dinamicamente desde el servidor?

Comment: Has utilizado el comando `php artisan storage:link`, de esta manera es como vinculas dicha ruta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lo que te recomiendo es que inspeciones elemento en el html y cual es la ruta que mostrando la imagen.

Comment: muchas gracias me sirvio mucho al parecer solo era que la extencion la estaba pasando en mayuscula y era minuscula en el archivo aunque no crei que por eso me dario problemas